# On fontSquirrel do i need the specimen files folder?

Tags: font-face

I've downloaded a font webkit from font Squirrel 
This one to be exact [GoodDog](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/GoodDog)

and in the floder there is a floder named specimen_files - What is it and do I need it for my site?

BTW - forst time using @font-face at all so...

Answer (score 5):

That folder just contains assets (images, scripts, etc) for the demo. You do not need to include it in your deployments.